# Forcing ngAnimate to respond immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a website using Angular and ngAnimate, here is example of my code.

#### Jade:

```
i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin.loader(ng-show!="isLoading")
```

#### CoffeeScript:

```
$scope.loading true
$http(
    url: $($event.target).attr('action')
    method: "POST"
    data: $.param($scope.user)
    headers:
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
).then (response) ->
    $scope.loading false
```

`$scope.loading` sets its argument value to the `$scope.isLoading`

E.g. when server sends the response with error, error shows immediately, and hence `$scope.isLoading` becomes false, but it takes ~1 second for `ngAnimate` to switch classes of the loader icon. 
So my question is, is it possible to force `ngAnimate` to respond on the change of the `isLoading` immediately?

Comment: Where is `ng-animatge`?

Comment: ngAnimate is run automatically when ngShow expression is true, so it switches the classes like ng-hide-remove and ng-hide-add, but the case is that when expression is false, there is a delay before the classes start switching again, do you see what i mean?